# Updating object in deeply nested arrays mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
{
  "_id": "659e76b929be316e566cdc36",
  "main_array": [
    {
      "_id": "659e76b929be316e566cdc39",
      "sub_array": [
        [
          {
            "_id": "659e76b929be316e566cdc3c",
            "info": {
              "_id": "654b725918297c74977025da",
              "title": "Cycling"
            },
            // Other fields
          },
          {
            "_id": "659e76b929be316e566cdc3e",
            "info": {
              "_id": "654b717718297c74977025c6",
              "title": "Running"
            },
            // Other fields
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "_id": "659e76b929be316e566cdc42",
            "info": {
              "_id": "654b725918297c74977025da",
              "title": "Cycling"
            },
            // Other fields
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the kind of structure I am currently working on for my project.

**What I need:**

I need to update `title` field where `info._id` field matches with the `given_id`.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried multiple queries like this

```
await MyModel.updateMany(
    {},
    {
      $set: {
        "main_array.$[].sub_array.$[].$[inner].info.title": new_title
      },
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: [
        { "inner.info._id": given_id },
      ],
    }
  );
```

OR

```
await MyModel.updateMany(
    {},
    {
      $set: {
        "main_array.$[].sub_array.$[inner].info.title": new_title
      },
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: [
        { "inner.info._id": given_id },
      ],
    }
  );
```

OR

```
await MyModel.updateMany(
    {"main_array.sub_array.info._id": given_id},
    {
      $set: {
        "main_array.$[].sub_array.$[inner].info.title": new_title
      },
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: [
        { "inner.info._id": given_id },
      ],
    }
  );
```

I found a lot more combinations after researching a lot but could not figure it out. All the solutions on the internet are about nested arrays of objects but in my case, I have an Array of Arrays of objects which is the main problem. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Your first version of `arrayFilters` seems [working fine](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jSKsT4YwqBS)

Comment: @ray yeah I just verified that again and it is working fine by adding the required filter to the filter object

Answer (score 1):

MongoDb playground link : https://mongoplayground.net/p/YBiH_WfjWFC

`outer & outer._id :` 
if it needs to match with ID of **main_array** element.

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    "main_array.$[outer].sub_array.$[].$[inner].info.title": "new_title"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "outer._id": "659e76b929be316e566cdc39"
    },
    {
      "inner.info._id": "654b717718297c74977025c6"
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, dear for putting your time. I just realised that my first query is working fine if I pass filter to the filter object. And I don't have to use `outer` placeholder as I need to update all the elements in the array which matches with `arrayFilters`

Comment: Ok No issue....